# Minimal X web browser with JavaScript support

Tags: ssh, xorg, software-recommendation, browser, javascript

I need to use a browser via `ssh -X` (that is, X rendering is allowed via ssh), but the browser should be as lightweight as possible, since the connection is not very fast then I need to minimize the amount of data exchanged because of the GUI.

Do you know any such browser?

To make an example with editors, if I try to use an editor like `kate` via `ssh -X` with a normal (i.e. not super-fast) connection then it is extremely slow, but if I use the graphical version of `emacs` instead, then it becomes very good, perhaps because it doesn't need to exchange data about the GUI interface via ssh all the time (I think with `emacs` all the data about the GUI are downloaded just at the beginning).

What browser would you suggest for this purpose? I know there are terminal-based browsers, like `links2` but I would need JavaScript support, so I cannot use it.

Comment: I would rather try to [transfer HTTP over SSH](https://serverfault.com/questions/78351/can-i-create-ssh-to-tunnel-http-through-server-like-it-was-proxy) and render it locally.

Comment: Many thanks for this comment @Melebius , it solved my problem! Although this question may be left without an answer, I hope other people thinking to the same solution (lightweight browser via SSH) will find this question and your comment, and therefore they will be encouraged to use SSH tunnelling instead.

Comment: @Kubuntuer82 Why not write your own answer and mark this question as solved?

Comment: @AnttiRytsöläCirclesConsult because unfortunately this question still has no answers, the comment I appreciated above contains just a workaround based on a completely different alternative, and if I converted it into an answer then it would not be a valid answer. Another thing which could be done is to just delete the question, but if I do this then other users struggling with similar issues would not find this useful piece of information (the comment) which would encourage them to find alternative good ways. So maybe it's better to leave it here although it will likely stay unanswered?